# Is there any method through which I can make the YouTube app use https connections instead of http?

Tags: internet, youtube, https

Well the question describes the problem.

I know that the YouTube app is not using secure connections, and I want to force the YouTube app to use secure connections. Can this be done?

Comment: Do you have a source for the YouTube app not using secure connections?

Comment: On my ISP youtube only works on SSL connections. So on the browser it's easy to use youtube since I use https, but can't do it on my phone

Comment: But have you actually inspected traffic from the YouTube app to verify that it isn't happening over HTTPS? It could be a separate issue going on with the app, and I'd be alarmed if some Google services weren't using HTTPS.

Answer (score -1):

on your phone. You can install firefox if you not already have it. Then open firefox and install [this extension](https://www.eff.org/files/https-everywhere-android.xpi) named https everywhere. it forces every site to load in https if it has https capability. It includes youtube in its list, so it may solve your problem for using youtube in https mode on your android.